# How to prove that the formula for the asymptotes of a $\csc$ function is true?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Trial and Error is not a proper method for proof. One can't prove using trial and error that ALL $\csc$ equations have the same asymptotes as the equation states... However, I have tried this equation and never failed.

warning, this may be very tough.

Here's the equation:
for a $\csc$ function such as

$$ \csc(bx-c)+d $$

the asymptotes are 
$$x = \frac{π}{b}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{2π}{b}n$$

Comment: Hint: The asymptotes for a $\csc$ function occur at the places where the $\csc$ function is undefined, which is when the $\color{blue}{\sin}$ function is $0$. Do you know when $\sin u$ equals $0$?

Comment: I understand, but i do not understand how this formula was derived. Thanks for hinting, I'm gonna give it another shot.

Comment: By the way, with that given formula (which is $bx-c =\pi + 2n\pi = (2n+1)\pi$, you will actually miss out some of the asymptotes (assuming $n$ is an integer).

Comment: sin (bx-c) = sin(pi) solving for x you obtain the formula. Is there a neater way that allows you to get the part with 'n'

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What you effectively want is all $x$ such that $\sin(bx - c) = 0$. To get this, recall that $\sin \theta = 0$ if and only if $\theta = n\pi$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the help.